# How to synchronize scrolling of the two QListWidgets?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qlistwidget

There are two `QListWidget` with the same number of the items. How can synchronize their scrolling?

I mean when I scroll one of them, the other one should get same scrolling.

Comment: Did my solution work?

Comment: @eyllanesc Need to synchonize updating. Added a comment to the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you have two `QListWidget` elements `listWidget_1` and `listWidget_2` in your `UI`, then you can  use `valueChanged`/`setValue` signal/slot pair to connect vertical sliders of both listwidgets, indeed, I didn't find any issue of signals re-bouncing in this "two way" connection because eventually both values will be same and I think no more signals would be emitted, thus you can set such sufficient connections:

```
    connect(this->ui->listWidget_1->verticalScrollBar(), &QScrollBar::valueChanged,
this->ui->listWidget_2->verticalScrollBar(), &QScrollBar::setValue);
    connect(this->ui->listWidget_2->verticalScrollBar(), &QScrollBar::valueChanged,
this->ui->listWidget_1->verticalScrollBar(), &QScrollBar::setValue);
// test lists:
    QList<QString> lw11, lw22;
    for (int x=0; x <200; x++){
        lw11.append("ListWidget1_" + QVariant(x).toString());
        lw22.append("The Other lw is at: " + QVariant(x).toString());
    }
    this->ui->listWidget_1->addItems(lw11);
    this->ui->listWidget_2->addItems(lw22);
```

---

If signal rebounce should be blocked anyway, then the model can be adjusted by adding a single `slot` to handle scrolling for both widgets and connect both to that slot:

```
    connect(this->ui->listWidget_1->verticalScrollBar(),&QScrollBar::valueChanged
 , this, &MainWindow::handleScroll);
    connect(this->ui->listWidget_2->verticalScrollBar(),&QScrollBar::valueChanged
 , this, &MainWindow::handleScroll);
```

and the slot logic can be :

```
void MainWindow::handleScroll(int value)
{
    // Logic for detecting sender() can be used ... but I don't see it's important
    // fast way to check which listWidget emitted the signal ...
    if (this->ui->listWidget_1->verticalScrollBar()->value() == value){
        qDebug() << "lw1 is in charge ...............";
        disconnect(this->ui->listWidget_2->verticalScrollBar(), &QScrollBar::valueChanged,this, &MainWindow::handleScroll); // prevent signal rebounce from the other lw
        this->ui->listWidget_2->verticalScrollBar()->setValue(value); 
        connect(this->ui->listWidget_2->verticalScrollBar(), &QScrollBar::valueChanged,this, &MainWindow::handleScroll);

    }else{
        qDebug() << "lw2 is in charge ...............";
        disconnect(this->ui->listWidget_1->verticalScrollBar(), &QScrollBar::valueChanged,this, &MainWindow::handleScroll);
        this->ui->listWidget_1->verticalScrollBar()->setValue(value);
        connect(this->ui->listWidget_1->verticalScrollBar(), &QScrollBar::valueChanged,this, &MainWindow::handleScroll);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You must use the `valueChanged()` signal from the `verticalScrollBar()` of `QListWidget`, since the connection is bidirectional, it will cause unnecessary tasks to be executed for it using `blockSignals()`:

In the next section I show an example:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QListWidget>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QScrollBar>

class Widget: public QWidget{
    Q_OBJECT
    QListWidget w1;
    QListWidget w2;

public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent=Q_NULLPTR):QWidget(parent){
        auto layout = new QHBoxLayout{this};
        layout->addWidget(&w1);
        layout->addWidget(&w2);

        connect(w1.verticalScrollBar(), &QScrollBar::valueChanged, [this](int value){
            w2.verticalScrollBar()->blockSignals(true);
            w2.verticalScrollBar()->setValue(value);
            w2.verticalScrollBar()->blockSignals(false);
        });
        connect(w2.verticalScrollBar(), &QScrollBar::valueChanged, [this](int value){
            w1.verticalScrollBar()->blockSignals(true);
            w1.verticalScrollBar()->setValue(value);
            w1.verticalScrollBar()->blockSignals(false);
        });

        for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
            w1.addItem(QString("item %1 of 1").arg(i));
            w2.addItem(QString("item %1 of 2").arg(i));
        }
    }


};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: The ScrollBars are synchronized. But the picture is updating only under the cursor.

Comment: blockSignals() works incorrectly for synchronization - content does not scroll. Only `valueChanged()` signal disconnect/connect works correctly.

Comment: @AlekseyKontsevich It works for me correctly, why do you say it does not work ?, connect and disconnect is not elegant at all.

Comment: @eyllanesc, as I said content does not scroll for me in this case, only scrollbars.

Comment: @AlekseyKontsevich 
Well, I find it strange, you have used my example, what version of Qt do you use?

Comment: Qt 5.11.1, I sync QTextBrowser with QTreeView.

Comment: @AlekseyKontsevich okay, I'll check where the problem is, when you indicate that something is not working you should point out the differences ;)

Comment: @AlekseyKontsevich How many lines of text does the QTextBrowser have and how many rows does the QTreeView have?

Comment: They have same number of rows of course as represent same content: JSON in text and tree view modes.